# How do I get the last available hook_update_N() for a module?

Tags: 8, updating

I'm having trouble getting a custom module to install and update successfully.  I'd like to examine the database for the modules update_N numbers. Is that possible? If it is, where do I look for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're in key/value storage, which in the database would be the `key_value` table. Look for entries with a `collection` of *system.schema*, and a `name` matching the machine name of the module you're interested in.

Through the API, it's a bit easier:

```
$current_version = drupal_get_installed_schema_version('name_of_module');
```

Comment: Thanks, Clive - Perfect! One thing still puzzels me though; when I uninstall then install the module the version number is restored to the higest _N in the install file and the install hook is run but none of the update_N functions are executed.  I'm guessing that maybe I could reset the version using the uninstall hook.  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks --- Mike

Comment: When you install a module, none of the `hook_update_N()` is invoked. Storing the higher update value is the right action Drupal does.

Comment: Update hooks are not for when a module is installed. For that, there is `hook_install()`, which is executed every time a module is installed, as in Drupal 7.

Comment: Yeah, what @kiamlaluno said. Think of `hook_update_N` as the way to get older versions of your module up-to-speed with the current codebase when it changes. For new installs, the current state of the module and any data it stores should be inline with what `hook_update_N` would have taken an older version to if it was upgraded

Comment: My instincts would have it different but as long as it's consistent that works too.  Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility as pointed in the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8#s-useful-drush-commands-while-developing-your-hook-update-n)

You could use drush and run the following command:

```
drush php-eval "echo drupal_get_installed_schema_version('module_name');"
```

to find the last applied update hook for a specific module.

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 10 would be:

```
drush php-eval  "echo \Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->getInstalledVersion('MODULE_NAME');"
```